# database says that it is inserting, but there are no records

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, insert

I'm sending a command to the database and it is returning that 1 rows are affected, but when i look inside the database, there are no records. I am receiving no errors. I checked to make sure the string was building correctly and it is. Any ideas? I'm not using parameterized queries here, I know. I will later. Here is the code from the database layer:

```
public int InsertStartTime(certificate cert, DateTime startTime, string lineNumber)
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO checkLog(userID,lineNumber,startTime) VALUES(" +
                         cert.userID + ", '" + lineNumber + "', '" + startTime + "');";
            int result = 0;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                comm.CommandText = sql;
                result = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            MessageBox.Show(result.ToString() + " rows affected");
            return result;
        }
```

Using an access 2000 db file:

```
string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\assets\users.mdb;Persist Security Info=True";
```

Comment: Is this being executed within a transaction?

Comment: nope. i didn't set a transaction, I thought about that like maybe it just needed to be committed. But alas, I did not set it up like this

Comment: Some DBMS don't autocommit by default, iirc. Did you actually try committing?

Comment: i tried just now. no dice. no errors.

Comment: What is `checkLog`? Is it a table or a view? Are there any triggers?

Comment: checkLog is a table. no triggers. SUPER simple setup here. I can connect and read from the database just fine.

Comment: Is the file read only? Does the process running the code above have write access to that file?

Comment: This code is **very** SQL Injection-y. You should **never** be constructing SQL statements by concatenation in this way.

Comment: @ben : please read the post regarding parameterized queries. All of the data being passed is done internally, there is no user input. and i said i'd do it later.

Comment: @RQDQ, I'm actually not sure how to check that

Comment: i checked file attributes, there are no restrictions

Comment: copied the sql string from debug and ran it inside of the access database itself. inserted fine. >:o|

Comment: @Sinaesthetic, I read it; it's just I work with a lot of very busy developers and I never trust 'later'... :-)

Comment: Would it have anything to do with the location of the database file? i have it inside of the working directory. I read something suggesting that there is a windows protocol that makes everything in there read only, but that just doesn't sound right to me

Comment: Yep... it has to be a permissions thing. I just moved the db to the desktop and tried it again and all is working as intended. Son of a... @RQDQ, if you post your suggestion in an answer, I will select it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click your database file in VS and look at the properties.  Is it set to "Copy Always"?  By default, visual studio will make a copy of your database for debugging and any changes will be made only to this copy and will not be reflected in the original.  You can set it to copy "Never" if you want to work on the "real" database file even in debug mode.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this. Been pulling (what's left) of my hair out for an hour or more trying to figure out why my records aren't getting updated when VS is saying they are.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the database / data provider you are using, your SQL command may not be executing in auto-commit mode.

Try committing your transaction explicitly. Something like this:

```
conn.Open();
using (var tran = conn.BeginTransaction()) {
    comm.Transaction = tran; // Possibly redundant, depending on database.
    comm.CommandText = sql;
    result = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    tran.Commit();
}
```

Comment: using oledb. tried this, same results. It says it is inserting/affecting 1 rows, no transaction object errors. Still no records actually being added

Comment: @Sinaesthetic what DBMS lies "beneath" your oledb provider? Also, are you sure you are looking at the same database instance your program is modifying?

Comment: its just an access 2000 db file (mdb). kinda hard to miss ;)

Comment: i guess I should have included that, modified post

Answer (score 1):

Nobody else pointed this out so I will.   PLEASE DO NOT USE SQL this way.  Use parameters. You leave yourself wide open to sql attacks otherwise.

```
  string sql = "INSERT INTO checkLog(userID,lineNumber,startTime) VALUES(@ID, @line, @starttime);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.CommandText = sql;
            comm.Parameters.Add("ID").Value = cert.userID;
            comm.Parameters.Add("line").Value = lineNumber ;
            comm.Parameters.Add("starttime").Value = startTime ;
            result = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```